# Labeling automatically the topics generated by BERTopic

Tags: python, topic-modeling, multilabel-classification

I trained BERTopic and get my topics. I want now to assign automatically labels to those topics. I came accross a framework called [Yake](https://github.com/LIAAD/yake). I would like to know if there is a python code to acheive this task or if you have any resource recommendations.

Comment: BERTopic does already extract keywords and names the topic accordingly. Do you want a one-word title, or what are exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I want one to two words title, like for example: data science as a topic or IoT as topic. hope I explained well

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are two ways to approach your goal:

1. Reducing the initial Keywords or vocabulary of the documents. Yake seems to be one way. The official BERTopic documentation suggest using KeyBERT. So, I would rather start with KeyBERT instead of Yake:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from keybert import KeyBERT

# Prepare documents 
docs = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',  remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))['data']

# Extract keywords
kw_model = KeyBERT()
keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(docs)

# Create our vocabulary
vocabulary = [k[0] for keyword in keywords for k in keyword]
vocabulary = list(set(vocabulary))
# Then, we pass our vocabulary to BERTopic and train the model:

from bertopic import BERTopic
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer_model= CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
topic_model = BERTopic(vectorizer_model=vectorizer_model)
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)
```

soruce: https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/tips_and_tricks/tips_and_tricks.html#keybert-bertopic

2. Reduce the number of words in the topic label `n` to the desired numbder (I assume mostly 1):

```
topic_model.generate_topic_labels(nr_words=1)
```

source: https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/bertopic.html#bertopic._bertopic.BERTopic.generate_topic_labels